# JOOQ - getPrimaryKey(), getIdentity() returns null

Tags: java, jooq

Using this:

```
System.out.println("PRIMARY KEY: " + DSL.table(DSL.name(tableName)).getPrimaryKey());
```

returning null :/ (also tried getIdentity())

before call getPrimaryKey I executing all query(s):

```
CreateTableColumnStep table = ctx.createTable(tableName).column("id", INTEGER.identity(true));
table.constraints(DSL.constraint("pk_" + tableName).primaryKey("id"));
```

> output of this in text is: create table filetest(id integer primary
>   key autoincrement not null, Meno varchar(21) null, Priezvisko
>   varchar(24) null, Vek int null);

so there is 'id' primary key... don't get it.

Also tried:
 ctx.meta(DSL.table("tableName")).getPrimaryKeys() or 
ctx.meta(DSL.tableByName("tableName")... returns me empty list

Answer (score 1):

> returning null :/ (also tried getIdentity())

When you call [`DSL.table(Name)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-org.jooq.Name-), you're creating table meta data on the fly. The only meta data you're providing is the (qualified) table name. You're not providing any column information, let alone constraint information, so you cannot really expect jOOQ to magically "know" that there should be a primary key somewhere.

> before call getPrimaryKey I executing all query(s):

It doesn't matter if you're creating a table by the same name prior to querying the primary key. For all jOOQ knows, this table meta information you've created is a table with a name and no columns / constraints.

> Also tried: ctx.meta(DSL.table("tableName")).getPrimaryKeys() or ctx.meta(DSL.tableByName("tableName")... returns me empty list

I can see how this can seem confusing. Contrary to calling `ctx.meta()` (which may be what you need here) and then querying that for your table, `ctx.meta(Table...)` just wraps the argument tables' meta information in `org.jooq.Meta` without connecting to the database.

Comment: So is there some way how to detect and return primaryKey ?

Comment: @Noro96: Yes, as I mentioned in the last paragraph: `ctx.meta()`

Comment: ctx.meta().getPrimaryKeys() 
Returns: [org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaPrimaryKey@360289a5, org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaPrimaryKey@b59f6bd, org.jooq.impl.MetaImpl$MetaPrimaryKey@5cf1f120]

But when I want to print by calling:  ctx.meta().getPrimaryKeys().get(0).getName() 
it returns null

Comment: @Noro96: Some JDBC drivers (which is what `ctx.meta()` is based on) don't return key names through `DatabaseMetaData`, I'm afraid. Anyway. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get all values but without column (and his values) that represents id (primary key), so i wanted to do it by 1.) droping this column or 2.)selecting all columns but without id column, but I have to get/detect which column is id - primary key.

Comment: Interesting, but why not use the code generator? I mean, you're going to look up this information at runtime every time you're running queries?

Comment: Yes, I am creating program that translate sql-csv/csv-sql, now I am doing part of obtaining values from generated/typed by user sql queries/statements, so after clicking button It will get all values from sql and it will create .csv format, I am not usiny your import/export csv, because it is not suitable for me -> so thats why I want those values, but without id column...but I dont know how to detect and return name of primary key

Comment: @Noro96: Well, I'm sorry to say again that runtime primary key information might not be as reliable as you wish. Of course, there could be a bug as well, which I would like to invite you to report to https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new, if you're sure there's a bug. Other than that, if you do have some compile time meta information available, I really recommend you use that instead.

Comment: I will probably handle it by regex or some similar way, but not sure if it will be working for all dialects, but thank you for your support and help